# Research within organisations

Tags: research-process, survey-research

I have just started working on a dissertation and I need to contact a number of organisations to get an idea of how they work.

What I am after is not sensitive in its nature. I just want to know what practices they apply to their tasks and whether they have developed anything  different that suits their needs or perhaps the tools they use.

However, I am being troubled by the following points:

- How can I assure the organisations that the information I require is not sensitive or for commercial purposes? My interests are purely academic.
- I am carrying out my research within an organisation. I am worried they might see me as competition. For the time being I have opted to not mentioning any organisation.

How can I go about assuring them that my interests are purely academic and convince them to reply back? What should I do?

Comment: this is a question about sociological research methods, not about academia.

Comment: It is still a question related to research methods within an academic context as far as I am aware.

Comment: Did you go through IRB? Did they have any suggestions?

Comment: When I have a question or request that is likely to be misunderstood, I start out with a phone call, to make that human connection.

Comment: @Dawn, the advice I got from 'Academics' was to not mention my being a part of an organisation up-front so as not to scare them off, but then inform them politely if I can get a conversation flowing

Comment: @aparente001 I should have thought of that from the beginning, its really what I should do. Unfortunately I cannot do that with every organisation since it would mean a number of overseas calls. But I could certainly call those which are based here!!

Comment: There are affordable ways of calling internationally.

Comment: "the advice I got from 'Academics' was to not mention my being a part of an organisation up-front so as not to scare them off, but then inform them politely if I can get a conversation flowing" - I don't understand.  Are you part of an organization?  If so, what type of organization?  Why might it be helpful not to mention this at the outset?

Comment: @aparente001 I am a research intern and I fear I might be seen as a 'competing' threat.

Comment: Well, thanks for explaining the subtext, but I still don't understand whether you are part of an organization, and what it might be.

Comment: Vote to close as "unclear what you're asking" because you first said "_What I am after is not sensitive in its nature_", Then you said "_I just want to know what practices they apply to their tasks and whether they have developed anything different that suits their needs or perhaps the tools they use._". I think you need to talk to your advisor to confirm  what you want to know is not sensitive at all because those info are pretty sensitive to me.

Comment: @scaaahu Why should you vote to close something you did not understand? What I would like to know is not sensitive information. An example is, how does the team work together, do they make use of existing frameworks to get the job done, did they tweak it to their advantage? A sensitive question might be more information related to their strategy and their clients. Something I won't ask about.

Answer (score 0):

In the US, if you are conducting a survey or certain type of interview, you need to have it approved (or declared exempt) by your campus IRB committee. This body will regulate what you need to disclose, and will also approve the wording of any cover letter.

In a written context, putting the cover letter on school letterhead should convey that the project is academic.

In an interview, you would likely state that you are a PhD student at UNIVERSITY and are working on a dissertation related to X to convey that your project is an academic one.

Comment: I just realized it is not clear from the question if this is a survey or an interview.

Comment: I was thinking more on the lines of an interview since I need to ask a number of open-ended questions

Comment: Okay, I think you should still work with IRB to make sure your project is complying with the rules and is exempt. Should probably be exempt if you are asking information on organizations and not information on individuals.